# Excel index match to return laegest value from multiple matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to index match some data into a table but as there are multiple matches Im not getting the match i need which would be the match with the largest value.
I have tried using maxif and lookup but had no luck as of yet with getting it to work.
One table has item number only, the next has item number, price and quote date but the same item can have up to 10 rows with different pricing/dates.
I'd like to pull in the most recent quote date with the item in table 1.
Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Can you show how you've tried MAX/IF or MAXIFS?

Comment: Can you clarify with an example? Stating a sample data and then expected result would help.

Comment: table 1 columns: item and vendor, rows unique numbers, table 2 columns item,  vendor, price, quote date with items repeated, I tried =MAX(IF([Item]=Table13[Item],IF([Vendor]=Table13[Vendor],Table13[Quote date])))

Answer (score -1):

I tried this concept before like this...

### First approach:

I added a column which has the following formula (assuming  that id in B:B) (put this formula in D:D column)

```
=A1 & "-" & countif(A2:A$999,A1)
```

for the childs table so i made  custom index for every single row

and then in the master table  (assuming you want to show the value of C:C)

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(A1&"-0",Sheet1!D:D,0))
```

### Second approach:

will be to use the new MAXIFS formula but you will need a newer excel version

for this approach you will need a sequent index column which just has the row number 1,2,3

and then use this formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MAXIFS(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!B:B,A1))
```